# trying to getting rid of /url?q=, not working

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can this string '/url?q=' that sits before each Google url be removed? I have tried regular expression, but it is not working.

```
<?php
   $url = "/url?q=http://www.testinstrumentsafrica.com/&sa=U&ei=dTTTU7L2A4egugSY44LgAQ&ved=0CBMQFjAAOGQ&usg=AFQjCNGIavZUP46nbvLPJUrDXTgC3QF6aQ";
   echo preg_replace("%/url?q=%", " ", $url);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need regular expresions for fixed strings:

```
$url = "/url?q=http://www.testinstrumentsafrica.com/&sa=U&ei=dTTTU7L2A4egugSY44LgAQ&ved=0CBMQFjAAOGQ&usg=AFQjCNGIavZUP46nbvLPJUrDXTgC3QF6aQ";
$url = mb_substr($url, 7);
var_dump($url);
```

... or plain `substr()` if you aren't using UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo preg_replace("%/url\\?q=%", " ", $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `?` or otherwise it represents an optional `l`

```
echo preg_replace("~\/url\?q=~", " ", $url);
```

The above code would replace the string `/url?q=` with a space.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bL1cV0/13)

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
$parts = explode('/url?q=', $url);
$justUrl = $parts[0];
```